# 1998 Ford Explorer loss of power on take off

Tags: ford, troubleshooting, explorer

Can bad gas or clogged air filter cause loss of power on take off?

The car was running fine then I fueled up and checked air filter immediately after it lost power.

Answer (score 3):

Tracy,

I've seen bad gasoline contaminate a Heated Exhaust Gas Oxygen (HEGO) sensor. Fill up with gas, five miles later check engine lamp comes on (i.e. a code is set. )  This causes permanent damage to the sensor.

But again these failures WILL set a code and turn on the Check Engine light.

And you've not mentioned the light coming on. Where are you located?  In many places your local auto parts dealer will read the codes for free. Gratis. At no cost.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say with the information given. Could be a lot of things.

• codes, even if the CEL isn't on there might be something stored.
• sensors - MAF, MAP, o2 would be most likely to cause these issues. Should be able to read with a multimeter.
• air filter
• spark plugs (clean, gapped correctly), wires, cap, rotor, coil
• vacuum lines (check engine vacuum)
• Idle motor - stuck open can be similar to a vacuum leak
• fuel filter, fuel pump (check fuel pressure)
• Clogged EGR valve
• Plugged cat

If you were really low on gas, you might has stirred up water or sediment in the bottom of the tank.

Since you say you checked the air filter, make sure you didn't knock something loose and the air filter hoses are installed nice and tight.  Air getting past the MAF would cause issues.

Comment: "Clogged EGR valve" will not cause significant power loss and will set a check engine light.